# Adding information to a plotly bar plot

Tags: python, plotly

**Disclaimer: It may be the case that plotly is not suitable for these tasks. If so, I'll be happy to have a pointer for a library that is relevant to the task.**

Given the following plotly barplot:

```
    fig = px.bar(
        loans_scores_df,
        x="Score",
        y="Count",
        color="Count", "features": "Features"},
        height=400,
    )
```

[image]

I'll be happy to generate a figure that summarizes the aggregated amount of scores under 0.9. One visual form of the idea I had in mind is:
[image]
But other forms of display are great as well.

Comment: I'm a little fuzzy on what you want to achieve, so I'm just confirming, are you looking for a way to add annotations? Or are you looking for a completely different way of visualization?

Comment: Yes, I'll be happy to add annotations that are defined adaptively by the number of bins. Adding both the arrow and text through Plotly's interface would be great

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two ways to add annotations: using the text mode for scatter plots and the add annotation function. I used the scatterplot text mode for annotations. The reason is that it is easier to set the coordinates. Also, for the arrows, I used the left and right arrows on top of each other. The arrow heads are set to style #2. As you can see in the comments of the code, the start and end positions are specified respectively, and the coordinate reference for each is x,y. If no text is used, specify blank.

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import numpy as np

hist, bins = np.histogram(np.random.randn(40000), bins=100)

fig = go.Figure(go.Bar(x=bins, y=hist, marker=dict(color=hist,)))

samples = hist[:25].sum()

fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(
    mode='text',
    x=[bins[25]],
    y=[hist[25]+150],
    text='{:,} samples'.format(samples),
    textfont=dict(size=24),
    textposition='top left',
    showlegend=False
    #yshift=100
))

fig.add_annotation(
    x=bins[5],  # arrows' head
    y=hist[25],  # arrows' head
    ax=bins[24],  # arrows' tail
    ay=hist[25],  # arrows' tail
    xref='x',
    yref='y',
    axref='x',
    ayref='y',
    text='',  # if you want only the arrow
    showarrow=True,
    arrowhead=2,
    arrowsize=1,
    arrowwidth=5,
    arrowcolor='#636efa'  
)

fig.add_annotation(
    x=bins[25],
    y=hist[25],
    ax=bins[6],
    ay=hist[25],
    xref='x',
    yref='y',
    axref='x',
    ayref='y',
    text='',  
    showarrow=True,
    arrowhead=2,
    arrowsize=1,
    arrowwidth=5,
    arrowcolor='#636efa'
)

fig.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Hi can I have a question that how can we change `textangle` of `go.Scatter` if we want to show it with `90 degrees`. Thank you.